# Set vertical-align to div using css

Tags: css, html

I have a `<a>` tag in `<div>` and I whant the text in `<a>` to be `vertical-align:middle;` but it is not working, the text is in the top. Why?

**CSS:**

```
div.banner 
{
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 18px 24px 50px 69px;
    background:url(banner.jpg) top center no-repeat;
    width:106px;
    height:38px;
    text-align:left;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

div.banner a
{
    display: block;
    width: 118%;
    margin-left:-13px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="banner">
  <a target="_blank" href="http://10.0.0.145/used-test-eq/bb_0">
    See All<br>used-test-eq
  </a>
</div>
```

Also I want the text to be in the horizon center, how??

Answer (score 1):

Add a line-height with the same height as the div.

> The vertical-align property can be broken down into three easy-to-understand steps:
>
> - It only applies to inline or inline-block elements
> - It affects the alignment of the element itself, not its contents (except when applied
>   to table cells)
> - When it’s applied to a table cell, the alignment
>   affects the cell contents, not the cell itself

See [Understanding CSS’s vertical-align Property](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-vertical-align/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a line-height to, add the line at the bottom.

```
div.banner 
{
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 18px 24px 50px 69px;
    background:url(banner.jpg) top center no-repeat;
    width:106px;
    height:38px;
    text-align:left;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height:38px;
}
```

Comment: I try it,It did't help, because the length of the text changes from times to times.

Answer (score 0):

The css code seen ok but vertical-alighn:middle; is spell wrong.
This correct spelling vertical-align:middle;